# Cumulative Distribution Function Proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have this proof formula for the Cumulative Distribution Function, and I understand it up till the point where we see square brackets.

But how did those end up there, and how did division end up there?

$X$ is a **geometric random variable.**

PDF: $\;\;\;P(X=x) \;=\; q^{x-1}p;\;\;\;x=1,2,3,\dots$

CDF: $\;\;\;P(X\le x) \;=\; P(X=1)+P(X=2)+\cdots+ P(X=x)$

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \;=\; p+qp+q^{2}p+\cdots+q^{x-1}p$

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \;=\; p[1-q^x]/(1-q)$

$\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \;=\; 1-q^x.$

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's simply an application of the formula
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}r^j=\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}$$
for $r\neq 1$ and $n\geqslant 1$ an integer.

Indeed, $(1-r)\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}r^j=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}r^j-r^{j+1}$ is a telescopic sum.

Comment: I somewhat understand but still feel confused :(

Comment: _What_ is confusing you?

Comment: where did that formula came from?

Comment: See edit. ${}{}$

Comment: Doesn't ring a bell :(

Answer (score 0):

$$PDF = P(X=x) = q^{(x-1)}\times p$$

$$CDF = P(X\le x) = q^{0}p+q^{1}p+q^{2}p+q^{3}p+q^{4}p...q^{x-1}p$$

$$\text{which is the same as } P(X\le x) =p\times \left(\sum_{i=0}^{x-1} q^{i}\right)$$

given $X$ is a geometric series:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} r^i = \frac{1-r^{n}}{1-r}$$

by using the above formula, we can rearrange the CDF as

$$P(X\le x) =p \left(\frac{1-q^{x}}{1-q}\right)$$
since we know that $p = (1-q)$ for probability, we can rewrite the above formula as:

$$P(X\le x) =(1-q)\times \frac{1-q^{x}}{1-q}$$
thus
$$P(X\le x) =1-q^{x}$$